# how do I allow django admin user to make money transfer which will deduct the sender account and credit the receiver account?

Tags: python, django-2.0

I have two tables -one for bank **accounts** and the other for **transactions**.
When a user makes a transaction( transfers money from his/her own account to another account): first I save the sender's account number, the receiver's account number, the amount that was sent and the date of the transaction into the transactions table, secondly I'm also able to deduct the amount from the sender's account balance in the accounts table and then add the amount to the receiver's account balance. All this is handled by a single view in **django**.

**The two tables and the view that handles the transfer are as follows:**

```
class Account(models.Model):
      ACCOUNT_TYPES = (
          ('SA' , 'Savings Account' ),
          ('CA' , 'Current Account' ),
          ('JA' , 'Joint Account' ),
      )
      owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      related_name='accounts', verbose_name='The related user')
      account_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES)
      account_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
      account_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2)
      last_deposit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
      interest_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
      date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.account_number



class Transaction(models.Model):
      owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, 
      null=True)
      from_account = models.CharField(max_length=13)
      to_account = models.CharField(max_length=13)
      amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
      date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

      def __str__(self):
        return str(self.amount)


    @login_required(login_url='../../accounts/login/')
def send(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.TransactionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sender = Account.objects.get(account_number=request.POST.get('from_account'))
            if sender.account_balance > decimal.Decimal(request.POST.get('amount')):

                trans =  form.save()
                trans.owner = request.user
                trans.save()

                # debit the sender account
                sender.account_balance -= decimal.Decimal(request.POST.get('amount'))
                sender.save()

                #credit the receiver account
                receiver = Account.objects.get(account_number=request.POST.get('to_account'))
                receiver.account_balance += decimal.Decimal(request.POST.get('amount'))
                receiver.save()

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('customers:history'))
            # else:
            #     return 
    else:
        form = forms.TransactionForm()
        return render(request, "customers/send_money.html", {'form': form})
```

But my problem is how to do the same thing when an administrator transfers money on behalf of a user. How do I deduct the amount from the sender's account balance in the accounts table and then add the amount to the receiver's account balance.

I will be much grateful if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

A 'dirty hack' workaround, but not so great because you won't know if the user deposits or withdraws while you're changing it, is in your admin.py file on your app. Example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Transaction, Account

@admin.register(Account)
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('owner', 'account_number', 'account_balance')
    list_filter = ('account_balance', 'account_type', 'date_created')
    list_editable = ['account_balance']
```

After doing the above the `account_balance` will then be editable from the admin panel. The downside is if a user had $100 and the admin wanted to take out 50, but the user just tried to spend 60 at the same time.

Or even worse: If you load the admin panel and the user has 100, and while your page is unrefreshed, they deposit 5000. Then you decide to take away 50 from the value you see because you didn't refresh it... Now they lose 4950.

There are ways to [make your own admin panel functions that can update it in real time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-actions). Check out how to do that there.